# Reiterate over Spock where block?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

We are using rest assured with Spock for our API testing.  We have a situation where we are reading in data from a CSV file.  So for this case let's pretend we are reading in 10 rows of data.  Is there a way we can repeat this single test, for these 10 rows of data, for a given amount of "companies"?  For example:

```
@Unroll
def "example test"() {
    when:
    //do something here

    then:
    //check something here

    where:
    row << functionalUtils.getRecordsFromCsv(csvFile)
}
```

This will run the test for however many rows are in the CSV file, so if there are 10 rows in the CSV file, it will run 10 times.

But let's say we have 4 companies we support that all have the same data and we want to verify all 4 companies are correct.  Instead of making that CSV file 40 rows (repeating the same 10 lines 4 times) we want to repeat this test 4 times with the 4 companies.  Something like

```
@Unroll
def "example test"() {
    when:
    //do something here

    then:
    //check something here

    where:
    company << ["company a","company b","company c","company d"]
    row << functionalUtils.getRecordsFromCsv(csvFile)
}
```

Am I making this harder than it is?  Is this even possible?  I know this is not correct and this will error, I'm just trying to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all companies have the same data in the csv file, you can use Groovy's [combinations()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#combinations(java.lang.Iterable)) together with [multi variable data pipes](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_multi_variable_data_pipes) in Spock.

```
where:
[row, company] << [
    functionalUtils.getRecordsFromCsv(csvFile),
    ["company a","company b","company c","company d"]
].combinations()
```

Comment: Looks like I need to upgrade to Spock 2, this is what I am looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, like I explained in my answer, there is no need to upgrade to Spock 2 for this and not even for my more versatile solution using different CSV files per company. I also explained why.

Comment: Yep, should be fully working with Spock 1.3. Spock 2.x added multi-assignment in the where block and nested multi-valued data pipes. But the shown solution uses neither of those.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how `functionalUtils` and `csvFile` are defined. I am assuming the former is a `@Shared` variable (otherwise it could not be used in the `where:` block) and the latter is a data variable defined right inside the `where:` block.

I am using [multi-variable data pipes](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_multi_variable_data_pipes), a feature which has been around for a couple of years, optionally in combination with [multi-variable assignment](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_multi_variable_assignment), a feature introduced in Spock 2.0-M3. This backward-compatible version of the test runs both in Spock 1.3 and 2.0:

```java
package de.scrum_master.q66485337

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class MultipleCompaniesCSVTest extends Specification {
  @Shared
  def functionalUtils = new FunctionalUtils()

  @Unroll
  def "company #company, row #row"() {
    expect:
    csvFile.startsWith(company)
    firstName.contains("-$company-")
    lastName.contains("-$company-")
    firstName.endsWith("-$id")
    lastName.endsWith("-$id")

    where:
    [company, csvFile, row] << getRecordsForCompanies("A", "B", "C", "D")
    id = row[0]; firstName = row[1]; lastName = row[2]
    // Since Spock 2.0-M3 you can simplify to:
    // (id, firstName, lastName) = row
  }

  private List<List> getRecordsForCompanies(String... companies) {
    def records = []
    companies.each { company ->
      def csvFile = "${company}.csv"
      functionalUtils.getRecordsFromCsv(csvFile).each { row ->
        records.add([company, csvFile, row])
      }
    }
    records
  }

  static class FunctionalUtils {
    def getRecordsFromCsv(String csvFile) {
      def company = csvFile.replaceFirst("[.]csv\$", "")
      // Emulate company-specific CSV file, creating some records
      (1..3).collect { id -> [id, "John-$company-$id", "Doe-$company-$id"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Since 2.0-M3 you can simplify `id = row[0]; firstName = row[1]; lastName = row[2]` to `(id, firstName, lastName) = row` if you wish to.

BTW, in Spock 2 unrolling is the default, so you can also omit `@Unroll` there.

*Disclaimer: There might be a more functional groovy way to create the values for the data pipe, something without imperatively modifying the state of a local data structure inside a closure or helper method and then returning the end result. Maybe there is some additional method for iterables, similar to `permutations()` or `combinations()`. If so, I have not found it, not being a Groovy expert.*

Comment: I think you were getting to something similar to Leonard's answer.  Thank you!

Comment: No, Leonard's answer is for a much simpler case, like he explained. If you look at my code, you see that I was assuming each CSV file to be company-specific with different content. This makes the necessary logic more complicated and cannot be handled like Leonard suggested. If I had assumed that you want to read the exact same CSV files for multiple companies, I would of course have suggested the same as him. I even mentioned `combinations()` in my disclaimer. Actually, I am really surprised that your case is so simple. Is it really?

Comment: BTW, I updated the sample code a bit in order to make the `where:` block look nicer by factoring out the lexical closure to the new helper method `getRecordsForCompanies(String...)`. It should be easier to understand what is going on now.

Comment: In this case it is as simple as using Leonards answer.  However I can see a use case for your answer in the future, so I definitely appreciate it.